# Systematic drift in total energy in MD simulation

Tags: energy-conservation, molecular-dynamics, conservative-field

I have been simulating a system of 10 particles interacting among themselves via Yukawa potential using Molecular Dynamics technique. In addition to the Yukawa interaction, there is an exterally applied time independent harmonic oscillator potential. I first bring the system to a desired thermal equlibrium state, by repeated rescaling of velocities. But when I decouple velocity rescaling thermostat I see there is some systemetic drift in system's total energy.
My question is : will the energy drift  be always there in the particular system mentioned above ? Or, this is due to some poorly chosen value of simulation parameters for example the timestep ?

Comment: What kind of integrator are you using?  If you want to preserve energy, you need to use [sympletic integrators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator). See [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/what-does-symplectic-mean-in-reference-to-numerical-integrators-and-does-scip) and [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20252/energy-drift-in-molecular-dynamics).

Comment: What is the simulation time ? For 10 particles I would expect no significant numerical errors for as long as few million steps (of your relevant time scale, i.e vibration or similar).

Comment: Considering the potentials I am taking, shall the energy be conserved ? And I am using velocity verlet.

Comment: With a Velocity Verlet algorithm, one should have a pretty good energy conservation *provided* i) the time step is at least 1/100 of the smallest natural period of the system (check the natural frequency of your harmonic potential) and ii) there is no mistake in the implementation of forces and energy calculations (it can be checked by evaluating the numerical gradient of the potential energy and comparing with the components of the forces. A check with a few atoms is usually enough).